# Trouble with type inference

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I've got following generic method

```
private static void ConfigureUpdateEntity<TUpdateEntity, TUpdateObject>(EntityTypeBuilder<TUpdateEntity> builder)
    where TUpdateEntity : UpdateEntity<TUpdateObject>
    where TUpdateObject : new()
{
    ConfigureBaseEntity(builder);
    
    [...]
}
```

When trying to call it like this

```
private static void ConfigureAdresseUpdateEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<UpdateEntity<AdresseUpdateObject>> builder)
{
    ConfigureUpdateEntity(builder);
    
    [...]
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> Error CS0411
> The type arguments for method 'SaiContext.ConfigureUpdateEntity<TUpdateEntity, TUpdateObject>(EntityTypeBuilder)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

UpdateEntity:

```
public class UpdateEntity<TUpdateObject> : BaseEntity
    where TUpdateObject : new()
{
    [...]
}
```

Please help me understand why the usage can't be inferred as I don't understand what is missing for the compiler.

```
ConfigureUpdateEntity<UpdateEntity<AdresseUpdateObject>, AdresseUpdateObject>(builder);
```

would work but doesn't seem necessary. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know exactly what as called, becuase of the nested generic, the `TUpdateEntity` is also a generic. The compiler just assuming the generic type from parameter itself only as I experienced. Does not trace parameter's nested generic types.

Comment: You're not missing anything, the compiler just cannot infer the type of `TUpdateObject`.